# HTML5 <datalist> Not working in packaged app

Tags: html, google-chrome-app

Using this example http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp
- I have no problem in browser, but it doesn't seem to work in packaged apps.

I am on Chrome v26. Version 26.0.1410.64 m. on Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what "doesn't seem to work" means, but [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=161302) suggests there are issues with datalist for extensions as well in Chrome. I've added a link to your question there so that when it's fixed, we can update this question.

Comment: Hey Sowbug, I did see that bug, I just wasn't sure if it applied to the packaged apps, just for clarification are extensions and packaged apps treated the same way? Doesn't seem to work isn't very helpful I didn't know what other way to say it. The "Autocomplete" that is suppose to appear, coming from the datalist, does not show up.

Comment: Packaged apps use some of the same infrastructure as extensions, so it's likely that the behavior you're seeing is related to the bug.